# Dynamically change Threadpool's size

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I am calling an external API with 10 threads in fixedThreadPool. Now I want to dynamically reduce this number of threads as API host is not able to handle those many requests in 10 threads. I want to reduce thread count to 5. And I want to do this without application restart i.e.
I want to dynamically change to fixed size thread pool's size. I can call setCorePoolSize(int) and setMaximumPoolSize(int) on my ThreadPoolExecutor. However, the javadoc says:

*Sets the core number of threads. This overrides any value set in the constructor. If the new value is smaller than the current value, excess existing threads will be terminated when they next become idle. If larger, new threads will, if needed, be started to execute any queued tasks.*

So when they say :***"excess existing threads will be terminated when they next become idle"***, When the excess existing threads will become idle? If my task queue is always full, can these excess existing threads become idle ?

Comment: It’s unlikely that it really matters whether you have five or ten threads. That doesn’t make a difference, even on my almost 30 year old Amiga500. If you rather want to limit access to a scarce resource, you are attempting to use the wrong tool for the job. Look at a semaphore or similar…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I want to dynamically reduce this number of threads as API host is not able to handle those many requests in 10 threads.

In which case, I suggest setting the number of threads to 5 from the start.  If you can't do this you could wrap each task in a semaphore so you can limit the number of concurrent tasks.

> When the excess existing threads will become idle?

When they haven't had a task to perform for a while (a minute by default)

> If my task queue is always full, can these excess existing threads become idle ?

no. It depends on the setting of the thread pool as to when a thread is retired but the default is 1 minute.